# SEO optimization multiple region site, domains and multilingual site

Tags: seo, multiple-domains, multilingual

I am taking SEO of our website to another level. I read a lot about it and study all aspects of how to properly handle multiple domains and languages. For now we use three domain names `www.myurl.eu`, `www.myurl.de` and `www.myotherurl.com`.

All sites were pointed to the same content on the same server. I have soon learned  that having multiple domains is not a good practice (good reading regarding this: http://www.seo.com/blog/multiple-domains-seo/). OK I solved this as suggested by SEO and Google experts, to pick one primary domain and do a `301 permanent redirect` from other domains! OK solved!

BUT! Then I attended on an technical SEO brief in UK, where a SEO guy was speaking  about local search and how UK Google search will prefer `.co.uk domains`. And as it turns out [he was correct](http://www.seoptimise.com/blog/2011/09/international-seo-strategy-domains-subdomains-or-subfolders.html). Also the link I have posted above there is also a paragraph regarding this:

> Country Specific Domains
>
> This is less of a tactic, and more of a “must do,” and is therefore my
>   exception to multiple domains. It’s an exception because all of the
>   problems above do not apply when you get into other countries. In
>   fact, in order to have the best results in international SEO, you’ll
>   need to have a country specific TLD (or top level domain). For
>   example, if you’re doing business in England, you will have a hard
>   time ranking without a .co.uk domain. You can still rank without a
>   country level TLD, but it’s an uphill battle. And by uphill, I mean
>   Rocky Mountains-type uphill.

Q1:
So OK, to rank high for my business in UK I will need a `www.myurl.co.uk`. I have bought one. Now question that arises from this. Is a `www.myurl.co.uk` again a 301 redirect to my primary domain or not? How should I handle this?

Q2:
Then there is a multilingual aspect of all this. My site is build in a way so Language sites are altered with an /lang/ code in url. Example:

- `www.myurl.eu/en/products` -> english products site
- `www.myurl.eu/de/products` -> same site in german
- `www.myotherurl.com/en/products` -> 301 redirect to
  `www.myurl.eu/en/products`

So now what to do with my country specific domains `www.myurl.co.uk` and `www.myurl.de`? Should these be 301 redirects to main domains like `www.myurl.co.uk` -> `www.myurl.eu/en/` and `www.myurl.de` -> `www.myurl.eu/de/`? Is this the right way to go with?

Q3: should I really go this way having separate country level domains in countries where I do business considering all my content is served from the same server? I also haven't seen let's say Apple or Microsoft having an `apple.co.uk` and so on? How important is this really?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to try and answer all three questions at once:

If you *really* want to "optimize" your domains then have each domain live, accessible (non-directed), hosted in their own counties, with their own carefully translated content based on the language of that country. Costly.

If you want to keep things as *simple* as possible (like Apple), then pick the .com domain, have the content for each country under a sub-folder (like `/uk/` or `/de/`), redirect your purchased ccTLDs to those sub-folder, and if those countries have different languages in the country (like both english and german in Germany), offer that as a sub-folder too (like `/de-en/`). Once you've done that, [set the country targeting](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=62399) in [Google Webmaster Tools at a sub-folder level](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34592), and implement their `hreflang` attribute to point Googlebot at the right page that matches the searcher's query (by language and location).

More reading:

- https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192
- http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content.html

Comment: Great answer Mike! I will go with the other way with sub-folder /uk/, /de/, etc and with redirected ccTLDs. If I go with the 'optimized' way it will be impossible for me to manage multiple servers and website instances... One question I have here. So having my ccTLDs redirected to appropriate sub-folder, will for example Google UK show my results as www.mysite.com/uk/products or www.mysyste.co.uk/products? Thanks again!

Comment: Google UK will show the URL redirected to - in this case the `www.mysite.com/uk/products` URL. You need to factor the impact that this *may* have on your UK visitors perceptions...

Comment: "You need to factor the impact that this may have on your UK visitors perceptions..." - what kind of impact are you talking about here Mike?

Comment: A UK searcher may look at a .com TLD's relevancy as being less than a co.uk TLD. This is purely subjective, of course. With big name brands (like Apple) doing the .com way the impact is not as big as it might have once been before.